# How to generate MTD (Month to Date) rolling sum in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, rolling-computation

I expected someone might have asked this before, but somehow I couldn't found anything. Please let me know if this duplicated.

So let's say I have a table in below format

```
| event_date | v |
|------------+---|
| 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| .......... | . |
| 2021-01-31 | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | 1 |
```

I would like to calculate the rolling sum of within each month. So the output would be like this (assume `v=1` for all row):

```
| event_date | v | cum_v |
|------------+---+-------|
| 2021-01-01 | 1 |     1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 |     2 |
| .......... | . |     . |
| 2021-01-31 | 1 |    31 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1 |     1 |
| 2021-02-02 | 1 |     2 |
```

This would be similar to calculating the cum sum of rolling 30 days, but instead it's rolling 1 month.

I think this can be done using hive's window function and `interval` command, but wasn't able to find any useful document on `interval` command. I'm also looking forward to do QTD and YTD rollup, so would hope to do this in a flexible manner.

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic function with partition by substr(event_date, 1,7) order by event_date:

```
select sum(v) over (partition by substr(event_date, 1,7) order by event_date) as rolling_sum
```

Comment: How come I didn't think of this... it's so easy

Answer (score 1):

You want a cumulative sum which looks like this:

```
select t.*,
       sum(val) over (partition by year(event_date), month(event_date)
                      order by event_date
                     ) as mtd
from t;
```

This easily generalized to YTD and QTD.

Or if you prefer a somewhat shorter form:

```
       sum(val) over (partition by last_day(event_date)
                      order by event_date
                     ) as mtd
```

I strongly recommend that you use date functions on date columns.